# Php Mongo Driver Is Not Making Connection to Authenticated Mongo Server

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to make connection to remote MongoDb host through PHP. The server has authentication enabled on it with a user name and password.
I am trying to connect it through php `MongoDB\Driver\Manager` class. But Its not giving me any kind of response.

I am trying to do it using following connection uri format:

`mongodb://[username:password@]host[:port][/[database][?options]]`

according to 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.construct.php

But there is no response in connection variable where I am receiving it.

```
<?php
    $conn = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/admin")
    var_dump($conn);
?>
```

In the password, there are no special characters except #. Also when I hit this url directly in command line then it gives:

`No such file or directory`

I think according to the documentation, this connection uri format is correct and it should make the connection. But I am kind of stuck here and don't know what to do further.

Comment: You should start by installing and using the correct driver. See [MongoDB PHP Library](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/). Connections for any code you are writing should be using `MongoDB\Client`. Be sure to read the instructions, since for PHP there are two parts to installing the driver. And be aware you need to install a MongoDB server or have access to an existing installed database server. Connection URI's also have nothing to do with the file system

Comment: @NeilLunn, the Mongodb is installed on the server. And I have to access existing installed database server. How Can I check if mongodb is installed to work with php or not (except shell) ?

Comment: Like when I installed it on local system I added mongo extension in php.ini file. Do I need to implement the same ?

Comment: Read the link. You are using the wrong driver. You have only installed one part of a two part installation. **None** of your code should touch `MongoDB\Driver` **directly**.